# I have an Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'department.PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

I'm new in mysql and don't know why I get an error I'm stuck here get an error in the foreign key one of the questions is

**The "DepartmentID" fields in both Employee and Project are foreign keys referencing the "Did" field of Department Table"** and when I insert a value in the department I get that error not sure why
``

```
`create table Department
 (
did     integer      default 1,
Dname   varchar(50) default 'HR',
location varchar(50) default 'Chicago',
primary key(did)`
```

);`

```
`create table Employee(
Eid     integer         default 12,
DepartmentID    integer  default 5,
Ename   varchar(50)     default 'Josh',
Erank   integer         default 2,
Salary  real            default 500000,
primary key(Eid),`
foreign key(DepartmentID) references Department(did)`
```

);

```
 `create table Project`
 (
     Pid integer                default 20,
     DepartmentID  integer   default 9,
     Pname varchar(50)      default 'Sorting',
     budget real            default 5.000,
     StartYear  integer     default 2000,
     primary key(Pid),
     foreign key(DepartmentID) references Department(did)
     );

     insert
     into   Department(Dname)
     values  ('Marketing'),
              ('Human Resources');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is required to specify the primary key value unless it is `auto_increment`

```
insert into Department(did, Dname)
values (1, 'Marketing'),
       (2, 'Human Resources');
```

Or alter your table to use `auto_increment`

```
create table Department (
did     integer   not null auto_increment,
Dname   varchar(50) default 'HR',
location varchar(50) default 'Chicago',
primary key(did)
);

insert into Department(Dname)
values ('Marketing'),
       ('Human Resources');
```

Comment: Thanks the auto-increment helped fix the issue.